# When is the differential entropy nonnegative?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

I'm  working  on research that is remotely related to information theory, and I have no expertise in the field. My question is: When is the differential entropy nonnegative? More specifically, if I  have a random vector that is not supported only over proper affine  subspace, is it true that its entropy is always nonnegative?  Why?

Comment: The sign of the differential entropy means basically nothing.

Comment: @leonbloy this doesn't answer the question!

Comment: ^I think it's basically the right response, if a touch offhand. In general, there's no sharp condition to assert positivity of differential entropy besides the trivial $\int p \log p < 0$, and you shouldn't be relying on its sign to make something general work.

Comment: For your specific question: take a random vector $X$, and let $\alpha$ be a constant. Show (using transformation of densities) that $ h(\alpha X) = h(X) + \log \alpha.$ This means that I can flip the sign of $h$ by just scaling - so if you gave me a random vector with positive differential entropy, I can produce, via a full rank linear transformation, a random variable with negative differential entropy. This in turn means that positivity of differential entropy cannot be characterised in terms of some property of a law's support that is invariant under full rank linear maps.